# HABTM relationship, How to input multiple values for id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model which has_many Portfolios, which has_many Assets which has_and_belongs_to_many AssetHistories.

Basically User 1 might have Google in their portfolio and User 2 might also have Google in their portfolio. Why populate the database with duplicate lines of stock price history for Google when I can have a many-to-many (HABTM) relationship. However what throws me off is what to put for asset_id in the AssetHistory model when it will be multiple values. I.e. it needs to reference both user 1 and user 2. User 1's Google might be asset.id 1 and User 2's Google might be asset.id 2. Therefore how do the entries in the AssetHistory model reference both the ids?

It seems pretty clear that asset_id can't be 2 values simultaneously but I can't wrap my head around this. Am I supposed to use a `foreign_key` and make Google the key? If so, I still have issues in my Asset model for what entry to put for Asset_History_id, because the asset Google, will have maybe 30 lines of stock price history. Each stock price history would be a different Asset_History_id.

Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong?

Note that I am using after_save in my asset model to populate the asset price histories. I.e. when someone adds an Asset, it populates the asset_history, but it doesn't populate the asset_history_id field in the Asset model and it doesn't populate the asset_id in the AssetHistory model because I'm at a lost on what to do there.

My asset model has:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :asset_symbol, :shares, :cost, :date_purchased, :asset_history_id 
belongs_to :portfolio    
has_and_belongs_to_many :asset_histories


after_save populatepricehistory

private
   def populatepricehistory
         #uses an api to download price data as an array and imports it to AssetHistory...
         #I expect something should go here to fill out the asset_history_id field in the Asset Model
         #while simultaneously filling out the asset_id in the AssetHistory model

   end
end
```

Asset History model

```
class AssetHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :close, :date, :asset_id, :asset_symbol
    has_and_belongs_to_many :assets
end
```

Migration for AssetHistoryAsset join table

```
class AssetHistoryAssetJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :asset_histories_assets, :id=> false do |t|
        t.integer :asset_id
        t.integer :asset_history_id
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :asset_histories_assets
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :through => :porfolios
  has_many :porfolios
end

class Porfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  has_many :users
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :portfolios
  has_many :portfolios
  has_and_belongs_to_many :asset_histories
end
```

By the way, do you really need a many-to-many relationship between `Asset` and `AssetHistory`? I would imagine each instance of `AssetHistory` to refer to only one `Asset`, probably by means of `belongs_to :asset` / `has_one :asset_history`.

Comment: each instance of AssetHistory would refer to multiple Assets. For example, Google owned by User 1 and User 2. In the Asset model, they have different Asset_ids because the first Google will have different price, shares, purchase_date etc associated with it than the second.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm suggesting a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Asset`.